# c++ return string causes free(): invalid pointer error

Tags: c++, string, pointers, return

Using g++ v4.8.2 on Linux Mint 17 32-bit computer, the following works fine. Also works fine on 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04.

```
...
string sdata;
sdata = decodeRec(bufp);
...

string Part::decodeRec(unsigned char *recp) {
    string line="";
    uint16_t typec; 
    memcpy(&typec, recp, 2);
    recp += 2;
    string sTypec = convertTypeToText(typec) + "  ";
    line += sTypec;
    // ... decode more fields in record, add string values to line
    return line;
}
```

But moving to a 64-bit Fedora computer using g++ 4.8.3, program crashes with the following:

```
free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000060f6e8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3a08c75a4f]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3a08c7cd78]
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x43)[0x3a170be1c3]
/home/myprogram[0x4072df]
...
```

It's the 'return line;' statement that fails. Its seems that some string library routine is trying to free a pointer more than once. I do not do any malloc() or free() in my program. During my debugging, I also saw this error: "double free or corruption."

Is the problem that the string variable line is a temporary automatic variable on the stack, and the return is getting messed up?
If so, what's the best way to correct this?

Should I do "static string line;"?
Or use an instance variable to hold line?
Or use string line = new("");

What exactly is happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: "What exactly is happening" is that your program has a bug.  Your program is calling a function `convertTypeToText` which we have no idea what it does.  We also don't know what `recp` is, whether your incrementing it by 2 has a bad side effect, etc.  Then you have the unknown `...` stuff which we don't know about.

Comment: Can you replicate this with a compilable example?

Comment: `Is the problem that the string variable line is a temporary automatic variable on the stack` No.

Comment: I was thinking the code is ok since it runs fine on two different 32-bit machines. The difference is the 64 bit machine. I've printed the string before the return and it looks fine.

Comment: See below where I'm asking what you're doing with memcpy().  You're not returning a temp auto variable.  It's copying 'line' on the way out creating a new std::string so that's not the problem.

Comment: If your application is a 64-bit application that was ported from 32-bits, be aware that there may be a size difference between types, especially pointers.  If your code is assuming that pointers are `x` bytes in size, then that is a problem.  Also, in general, if a program fails to run on one platform, it could mean that the program always had a bug (or improper coding that by luck happens to work for 32-bit), but now it's being exposed.

Comment: if `recp` aliases a `uint16_t`, you can simply do `typec = *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(recp);`, no need for memcpy

Comment: @Alex_B - You need to post `convertTypeToText`.  Also, passing an unsigned char pointer and just assuming it has at least 2 bytes of information...why?  You're using C++ -- why not a `std::vector<unsigned char>`, where you know what the size will be without assumption?

Comment: The main problem here is on line 42.

Answer (score 0):

This line here might be bad

```
memcpy(&typec, recp, 2);
```

Are you sure that recp is at least 2 bytes long?

Usually crash on return means that memory was corrupted during the function, not necessarily during the return statement

Comment: Unlikely to be the problem; it should explicitly be 2 bytes.  (pointer to uint16_t)

Comment: If recp is null then this may corrupt memory without crashing right away

Comment: @Eric If recp is null then `memcpy` should segfault right away, no?

Comment: Ya, null will probably crash, but deleted memory, or slightly out of bounds might not

Answer (score 0):

In your memcpy(&typec, recp, 2);

What exactly is typec?  It should be a pointer to a buffer holding the destination, but 
you're just giving it a pointer to a short int.  That's what I'd call a code smell.
(Actually I don't think that's the problem)

Comment: The memcpy is decoding a response from a server which is 2 octets. I actually do ntohs() on it but left that out for simplicity.

Comment: Is it possible 'recp' could be null?  memcpy may not like that.  Ok it's likely the memcpy is ok since it should explicitly have a 2 byte destination.  What about something inside convertTypeToText()?